# Should I worry about OkHttp 4 Connection Pools?

Tags: java, okhttp

I used to create OkHttp Clients like this:

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionPool(connectionPool)
                                 .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeout))
                                 .connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(timeout))
                                 .addInterceptor(logging)
                                 .build();
```

But now I'm getting a warning about `connectionPool` being kotlin internal (I'm using it from java).

It seems related to upgrading to OkHttp 4.

Should I forget about pools and let OkHttp handle it?

If I create many OkHttpClients within my application. If I don't configure the pool, will they use the same pool, or each client will have it's own pool? I have one application with many different HTTP connection usage scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/):

> OkHttp performs best when you create a single OkHttpClient instance
> and reuse it for all of your HTTP calls. **This is because each client
> holds its own connection pool and thread pools**. Reusing connections
> and threads reduces latency and saves memory. Conversely, creating a
> client for each request wastes resources on idle pools.

So, yes, **each client will have it's own pool**.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation does not give details to clarify if I just let it alone or on which scenarios should I configure it. Does `new OkHttpClient.Builder()` creates a new pool? Or does OkHttp have a global pool?

Comment: I focused and improved the question.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still unsure about the warning `new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectionPool(connectionPool)` being kotlin internal.

Comment: What's exactly the warning?

Comment: Usage of Kotlin internal declaration from different module. It's an intellij idea warning, but inspecting the code `.connectionPool` is declared as internal.

Comment: weird, it seems a bogus warning, since there's a non internal function with the same name.

Comment: Probably, the confusion is because of [`connectionPool` internal var](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/d602ba275e93c22c512847765e303d8c6c3b3c10/okhttp/src/jvmMain/kotlin/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt#L512). But you're right, seems like a *bogus warning*.